# Irreducible vs Primes (Unique factorization of primes proof does not hold for irreducible factors of set of 1,4,7,10....)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

I am reading the following problem:

> If T = ${1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, ...}$
> then show that the factorization of elements of $T$ into irreducible factors is non unique and find $3$ examples. An element of $T$ is called
> irreducible if it is $\ne 1$ and the only factors with $T$ that it has
> is $1$ and itself

My approach:
a) Any element $n$ of $T$ can be factored as a product of irreducible factors since each element $n$ is either irreducible so there is no need to prove anything further or is composite i.e. there is some $d$ that divides $n$. This means that $n = d\cdot e$ for some $e$. And each of these factors are either composite or irreducible. Following the same logic we break down further and further till we would need to reach an irreducible. Basically it is exactly the same logic for the primes and counting numbers set.

b) We know that an element $n$ can be expressed as a factor of irreducible numbers (which in my understanding "irreducible" $\equiv$ prime).
If the factorization is not unique it means that we have a number $N$ that can be written in $2$ ways:
$N = 1^{e1}\cdot 4^{e4}\cdot 7^{e7}\cdot 10^{e10}...p^{ep}=1^{f1}\cdot 4^{f4}\cdot 7^{f7}\cdot 10^{f10}...p^{fp}$
Where $e^n$ and $f^n$ are the exponent of the $n$ irreducible number and $p$ is some irreducible number.

If the factorization is not unique then this means that $e^p \ne f^p$
Assume that $e^p \le f^p$ so we define $d_p = f^p - e^p$. If we divide $N$ with $p^{ep}$:

$$\frac{N}{p^{ep}}= 1^{e1}\cdot 4^{e4}\cdot 7^{e7}\cdot 10^{e10}... p^{0}= 1^{f1}\cdot 4^{f4}\cdot 7^{f7}\cdot 10^{f10}...p^{dp}$$
If $dp > 0\space $ then this means it would divide both sides and hence divide an irreducible term which is impossible.
Hence the factorization has to be unique. This is the same proof we use for the counting numbers set.
But the problem is that the factorization of this set is indeed non unique e.g.

$100 = 4 \cdot 25 = 10^2$

So I don't understand what is wrong here. Why does the standard proof for primes does not work for this set of numbers?

**Update:**
It seems that the key issue here is if the euclidean lemma is applicable. My understanding was that $gcd(10,4) = 1$ so the lemma would be applicable. But then there was a counter example already provided i.e. $10^2=4\cdot 25$ which I did not come up with so, I am confused
a) when we define a new arbitrary set, which know rules are applicable. E.g. $gcd(10,4) = 2\space$ but $2 \notin T$
b) Without the counterexample given how could I have noted/proven the lemma does not hold?

**Update 2:**
After the comments of @Infinity_hunter, @TonyK and @arbashn I see that there is a confusion due to my terminology.
The textbook I am reading defines the Euclid's lemma as follows:

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be integers. If $a\mid bc$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$
> then $a \mid c$

Following that the textbook specializes the lemma for when $a$ is a prime and then goes on to show the uniqueness of prime decomposition.

These are the only premises I was working on and am/was aware and why I have been asking about the $gcd$ in my comments.
So is there a more appropriate definition of the euclidean lemma/primes that I should be familiar with?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: sorry typo. Corrected it

Comment: The problem is that here there are irreducibles which are not prime i.e. if $t$ is an irreducible which is not a prime then for some $a,b$ we will have $t | ab$ but $t$ doesn't divide any of $a,b$

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: I am not sure I understand this; for this particular set, the irreducible and primes are equivalent terms. I.e. in my mind they are basically exactly the same thing. So what exactly do you mean by there are irreducibles which are not prime? Isnt the idea to use only the numbers of the specific set?

Comment: An element p is said to be prime if for any $a,b$ in the domain , $p \vert ab$ implies $p | a$ or $p |b$. Note that here $10$ is irreducible but not prime

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: But $10$ can not be divided by any number of $T$ except $1$ and $10$. Doesn't that make it prime for $T$? May be I am confused on this part. I thought a prime is an element of a set that is irreducible for that specific set.

Comment: I.e. the counting set

Comment: In general primes and irreducibles are two different things. I have already given the definition of prime in an earlier comment. You are essentially using the property of primes for irreducibles in your proof. Let me write that as an answer

Comment: Jim, just to make it perfectly clear: @Infinity_hunter's defintion of prime doesn't use the natural numbers, it only uses elements of the set $T$. $10$ is not prime in $T$ because $10$ divides $4\times 25$ but $10$ doesn't divide $4$ or $25$. Note that $4$ and $25$ are both in $T$.

Comment: @TonyK: Isn't that definition of primes based on commutative rings? In the book I am reading there is nothing about rings mentioned, only euclidean lemma and that primes have no factors besides $1$ and themselves. So is that definition somehow implied in the lemma and I missed the point? Or was the knowledge of rings expected?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The definition is not "based on" commutative rings; it stands by itself. $p$ is prime in $T$ if whenever $p$ divides $ab$ with $a,b\in T$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. Nothing about rings in there!

Comment: @TonyK: Isn't this is the definition you are referring? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Definition: "An element p of **a commutative ring** R is said to be prime...." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @TonyK: Otherwise where is that definition coming from?

Comment: $T$ is not a ring, as you know. But the usual definition of prime makes sense in $T$, don't you agree? Anyway, that's all I have to say.

Comment: @TonyK: I guess that is the confusion. The book so far presented as a definition of prime "a positive integer, $\ne 1$ whose only positive factors is $1$ and itself. That was the definition I also was aware. Then it presents the euclidean lemma and as a special case when the divisor is a prime number and then proceeds to show the uniqueness of primes. So the definition you are mentioning and that you say is not related to rings, is it an alternative definition I should have known? Because just from reading about the lemma in the book I didnt realise that definition if it was implied

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: same comment as above

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: I did another update in the post

Comment: @TonyK:  I did another update in the post

Comment: @arbashn:  I did another update in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of irreducibles which is mentioned in the question is perfect.
Now you may observe that there are elements (say $p$ ) in $T$ such that for any $a,b \in T$, $p$ divides  $ab$ implies that $p$ divides $a$ or $b$. We call such elements as **[prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Definition) in $T$**. For example, $7$ is a prime in $T$  because $7$ is a prime in $\mathbb{N}$ and we can make use of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) to conclude. Note that $7$ is also irreducible.

Also we can see that $10$ is not a prime in $T$. To see that we take the same example which you provided, take $ab = 100, a= 4, b =25$, so $10$ divides $100$ but none of $a,b$.

It is possible that an irreducible $p$ (such as $10$) can divide $1^{e_1}\cdot 4^{e_4}\cdot 7^{e_7}\cdot 10^{e_{10}}... $ without dividing any of $1,4,7, \dots$, etc.This was a flaw in the argument.

You can easily apply your argument to the sets where each irreducible is a **prime in that set**.

**Update:**

I think OP considering as Euclid's lemma is the generalization of Euclid's lemma given here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma .
It says that

> Euclid's lemma — If a prime $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two integers $a$ and $b$, then $p$ must divide at least one of those integers $a$ and $b$.

Note that the lemma does not make use of the concept of $\gcd$.

I don't think we can show that the lemma does not hold in $T$ without exhibiting counterexamples.  When we define a new structure on sets, we **appropriately define** a set of rules or axioms which the elements of the set should satisfy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126947/discussion-on-answer-by-infinity-hunter-irreducible-vs-primes-unique-factorizat).

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: "For example, 7 is a prime in  because 7 is a prime in ℕ" this is clear. "Also we can see that 10 is not a prime in ". Why did you need to use an example to show this? Wouldn't the statement "because 10 is **not** a prime in ℕ" suffice as it did for $7$?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: "When we define a new structure on sets, we appropriately define a set of rules or axioms which the elements of the set should satisfy." who was supposed to define that? The author of the exercise?

Comment: I'm using the definition of prime that I mentioned in the answer to show that certain number is prime or not prime.

Comment: "Who was supposed to define that?" Well, the answer is mathematicians.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: I meant that for $7$ you just used the fact that it is prime in natural numbers `For example, 7 is a prime in  because 7 is a prime in ℕ`. You did not need to provide some examples. Why for $10$ did you have to provide examples and not just say that it is not prime in naturals?

Comment: Not alone the fact that 7 is a prime in natural number is sufficient to show that it is a prime in T,  we used the fact that primes in $\mathbb{N}$ satisfy Euclidean Lemma (which was the definition of a prime in T)

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: Ah got you now. You mean that both conditions should hold concurently, i.e. that $7$ is a prime in $T$ **and** the euclidean lemma holds. Sorry I didn't understand that originally. I read the statement `7 is a prime in  because 7 is a prime in ℕ and we can make use of Euclid's lemma` as "because 7 is a prime in ℕ it is in T and therefore based on Euclid's lemma...."

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: thank you for explaining. Is there somewhere I can read about the caveat of that original definition of primes i.e. (numbers with factors 1 and themselves) and how that it does not hold correctly in other domains? I suppose that is more of a math history topic? I wasnt aware of that subtle difference

Comment: Generally, the generalization of the notion of primes is introduced in algebraic structures such as rings and integral domains. I am not sure whether there exist some other generalizations. Just for curiosity, in which book you found this exercise?

Comment: @Jim I think it's best to study two different definitions for irreducible and prime. If you study them as the same thing (which they are for the positive integers), it's going to be more confusing when you encounter more exotic sets (like $T$ or $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$). You seem to sometimes use prime and irreducible interchangeably when referring to $T$, so please be careful about that.

Comment: For your confusion regarding $7$ and $10$, irreducibility is a property that "trickles down" but does not "trickle up" i.e if $a$ is irreducible in a set (in this case, $\Bbb{N}$), then it is irreducible in any subset of $\Bbb{N}$ (like $T$). But the converse isn't true, for example, $10$ in $T$. So you cannot say if $10$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb{N}$, then it is not irreducible in $T$. Same applies to primality, but that is a little less obvious.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter: "An illustrated theory of numbers"